# How to temporarily disable / remove Vuforia in XCode

Tags: ios, vuforia

I'm developing an app that uses Vuforia.  I would like to temporarily disable Vuforia so that I can run my app in the simulator, rather than on the device.

As I only have one iPhone, I would like to see how the app looks on other devices via the simulator

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This can be done by let Xcode not link the **libVuforia.a** and not compile any .m/.cpp/.c file that you import/include Vuforia header file.

**YourProject->YourTarget->Build Phases(Please see the attached image)**

1, Chose "Link Binary With Libraries", set "require" to "optional";

2, Chose "Compile Source" and select any file that you import/include Vuforia header files, click the "-" button(if you want to run the app on a real device add them back);

3, Build & Run on Simulator.

Comment: Hey Meonardo.  I'm going to try this later but I want to thank you in advance.  It's been hell not being able to run my app in the simulator.  Thank You, Thank You!

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Glad to help, I tested it and work fine on Simulators.

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment out `startCamera`, and the initialization of the vuforia services / trackers you use. Also, if your app is built properly - it should fail if the init did not succeed, so make sure you disable this behavior for the emulator testing.